# set config/routes for accept parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need set the route en config/routes for accept this route when I push the submit button in the form

```
<% form_tag(:controller => "students", :action => "index", :q1 => "v1", :q2 => "v2") %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

Browser

Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"students", :q1=>"v1", :q2=>"v2"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating a form that gets submitted at `index` action?

It is by default a `get` action and form submission is a `post` request. So, there are no routes defined for this request.

By convention, it should get submitted to a `Post` action.